# JavaScript Regular Expression for CSS Background HEX/RGB and URL

Tags: css, regex, url, rgb, rgba

I'm looking for a regular expression which can turn the following CSS Declaration:

```
background: #ffe300 url(image.png?id=848) !important;
background: rgb(0,0,0) url(image.png?id=848) !important;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9) url(image.png?id=848) !important;
```

Into an array of color and URL

```
array[#ffe300, image.png?id=848]
array[rgb(0,0,0), image.png?id=848]
array[rgba(0,0,0,0.9), image.png?id=848]
```

I already found this expression here which works perfectly for HEX, RGB and HLS as well: https://www.regexpal.com/97509

And for the URL grabbing I'm using

```
/https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/
```

Which also works fine but I did not manage to combine both. Maybe something can help me in this case.

Comment: Something like this: https://regex101.com/r/gxSTT7/1?

Comment: Thanks, @randomir. Yes, something like this by the example is python example. How can I turn this into a JavaScript regex?

Comment: Didn't know you need JS. Just replace named groups with positional: https://regex101.com/r/gxSTT7/3

Comment: Cheers mate! Works perfectly.